# Delete duplicates in Excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking for some sort of macro that deletes duplicate words within cells in a spreadsheet.

For instance, if cell A1 = "John John" I would like my macro to delete the duplicate "John". In other words A1 will become "John".

I have found a set of code that I have tweaked to some degree to fit my needs:

```
Sub Remove_DupesInString()

'this loops through the specified range and erases duplicates


Dim starval As String
Dim finval As String
Dim strarray() As String
Dim x As Long
Dim y As Long
Dim k As Long
' step through each cell in range

For Each cell In Sheets(5).Range("D2:D6507")

            Erase strarray ' erase array
            finval = "" ' erase final value"


            starval = cell.Value

            strarray = Split(starval, " ") 'Seperator is space

            'Step through length of string and look for duplicate
            For rw = 0 To UBound(strarray)

                        For k = rw + 1 To UBound(strarray)
                                If Trim(strarray(k)) = Trim(strarray(rw)) Then
                                strarray(k) = ""  'if duplicate clear array value
                                End If
                         Next k
            Next rw
            ' combine all value in string less duplicate
            For x = 0 To UBound(strarray)
            If strarray(x) <> "" Then

            finval = finval & Trim(strarray(x)) & ", "
            End If

            Next x
             ' remove last space and comma
             finval = Trim(finval)
             finval = Left(finval, Len(finval) - 1)
             ' Replaces cells with new values
             cell.Value = finval

Next cell

End Sub
```

This set of code is sensitive to blank spaces in each cell. If, in cell D2, I have "John John" and in cell D3 have "Mary" it will produce the following:

D2 = "John", D3 = "Mary"

It does not seem to work, however, if I have blank cells in the column I'm running my macro in. I have worked around this issue by sorting on the cells with data inside them and only running my macro in this range.
I've tried tweaking the code further by adding different `If` cases with `isEmpty()`. My initial thought was that the the code above would only be executed `If not isEmpty() Then` but I've had no luck here. I'm not quite sure what to put inside the `isEmpty` function. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a code/SQL/regex writing service, where you post a list of your requirements and language of choice and a code monkey churns out code for you. We're more than happy to help, but we expect you to make an effort to solve the problem yourself first. Once you've done so, you can explain the problem you're having, include the **relevant** portions of your work, and ask a specific question, and we'll try to help. Good luck.

Comment: So if cell A3 contained "Leelee" and A4 contained "Lee", should A3 be changed to be just "Lee"?  i.e. is case and/or embedded space significant?  And if cell A5 contained "Lee Anne", should it be left unchanged, or changed to "Anne", or changed to "Lee"?

Comment: Judging by the code, the fact that A2 (and D3) contain "John" has got nothing to do with the question - you are simply trying to remove any duplicated words within each individual cell.  So if A1 had "John John" and A2 had "Mary" (and even if "John" exists in no other cell in the spreadsheet) you would still want A1 to become "John".  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct. I only want to remove words duplicated inside each individual cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say, your only problem appears to be the handling of cells which are empty.  That can easily be overcome by simply not processing any cells where the cell doesn't contain a space:

```
Sub Remove_DupesInString()
    'this loops through the specified range and erases duplicates
    Dim starval As String
    Dim finval As String
    Dim strarray() As String
    Dim x As Long
    Dim y As Long
    Dim k As Long
    ' step through each cell in range

    For Each cell In Sheets(5).Range("D2:D6507")
        finval = "" ' erase final value"

        starval = cell.Value
        strarray = Split(starval, " ") 'Seperator is space
        If UBound(strarray) > LBound(strarray) Then 'i.e. there was a space
            'Step through length of string and look for duplicate
            For rw = 0 To UBound(strarray)
                For k = rw + 1 To UBound(strarray)
                    If Trim(strarray(k)) = Trim(strarray(rw)) Then
                        strarray(k) = ""  'if duplicate clear array value
                    End If
                Next k
            Next rw
            ' combine all value in string less duplicate
            For x = 0 To UBound(strarray)
                If strarray(x) <> "" Then
                    finval = finval & Trim(strarray(x)) & ", "
                End If
            Next x
            ' remove last space and comma
            finval = Trim(finval)
            finval = Left(finval, Len(finval) - 1)
            ' Replaces cells with new values
            cell.Value = finval
        End If    
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked like a charm! I salute you sir! Thank you